# How do I format names to capitalize the first character of every name/word separated by either spaces or hyphens?

Tags: javascript

There are lots of simple solutions out there to format the first character in every word by splitting a string (using `split(' ')`) but nothing explained how to handle real-world examples where people may have more than 1 word in their name, AND these words may be separated by spaces OR hyphens.

If you've found a more elegant solution, please share. I did my fair share of Googling but came up empty so I posted this.

**Example Data**

- Norm garcia -> Norm Garcia
- stephen white-black -> Stephen White-Black
- Lucy-lou ladyface -> Loucy-Lou Ladyface
- Billy joe davidson -> Billy Joe Davidson
- bobby savannah nick-nickerson -> Bobby Savannah Nick-Nickerson

Ideally, I'd like to see solutions that don't involve regex, but feel free to add your regex answers if you think they're simpler.

**Bonus Points**

Bonus points if you can show how to handle names like DeSouza, FitzGerald, McDonald, MacIntyre, O'Henry, etc.

Comment: As mentioned here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322079/please-help-with-regex-statement-for-names-like-obrian-or-macdonald  The bonus points one is more tricky, and the only real solution is a lookup table of names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How's this?

```js
const inputData = {
  firstName: 'First name',
  lastName: 'last-name',
}

function formatName(name) {
  let formattedName = name.split(' ')
  formattedName = formattedName.map((word) => {
    return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1)
  })
  formattedName = formattedName.join(' ')

  let hyphenIndexes = []
  for (let i = 0; i < formattedName.length; i++) {
    if (formattedName[i] === '-') {
      hyphenIndexes.push(i)
    }
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < hyphenIndexes.length; i++) {
    // capitalize the character after the hyphen
    formattedName =
      formattedName.slice(0, hyphenIndexes[i] + 1) +
      formattedName[hyphenIndexes[i] + 1].toUpperCase() +
      formattedName.slice(hyphenIndexes[i] + 2)
  }
  return formattedName
}

const fullName = formatName(inputData.firstName) + " " + formatName(inputData.lastName)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression with `\b` to match the start of a word and `\w` to match the first character of said word. [More about `\b`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions).

```js
const names = [
    'Norm garcia',
    'stephen white-black',
    'lucy-lou ladyface',
    'billy joe davidson',
    'bobby savannah nick-nickerson',
];

for (let i = 0; i < names.length; ++i) {
    names[i] = names[i].toLowerCase().replace(/\b\w/g, m => m.toUpperCase());
}

console.log(names);
```

Comment: True, but for beginners the regex world is dark and scary. Do you have a good suggestion that doesn't use regex? It might involve a bit of extra code, but I bet you there's a better way than what I've posted.

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` and in one iteration check for previous char is "-", " " or start and do uppercase conversion of that char.

```js
const capSentence = (line) =>
  [...line]
    .map((char, idx, arr) =>
      [undefined, " ", "-"].includes(arr[idx - 1])
        ? char.toUpperCase()
        : char.toLowerCase()
    )
    .join("");

console.log(capSentence("Norm garcia"));
console.log(capSentence("stephen white-black"));
```

Comment: This is nifty. Any ideas for names like DeSouza, LaFontaine, etc? In these examples, we'd assume the user entered the name with appropriate capitialization. We still want to properly format garbage like MyLaStNaMe and transform to Mylastname.